# Creating column from categories in a column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe in which I want to create columns based on the levels of data from that column. For example,

```
Cust_ID  MCC  Date TRANS_AMT Frequency
1       1750  Jan    6633        1
1       1799  Jan    5584        1
2       3001  Mar    405         2
2       3174  Oct    1219        1
```

I want to create columns based on the levels of data I have in column MCC and Date. For each Cust_ID, I want TRANS_AMT and Frequency they have done at each MCC and Date level combined.

Below is the required output:

[image: Sample Output]

Answer (score 0):

Because ordering of columns in final DataFrame should be important, convert column `date` to [ordered categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html), then create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and columns `TRANS_AMT` and `Frequency` convert to ordered [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html) too.

Then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and sorting by second level of `MultiIndex` in columns by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

Last flatten values in list comprehension with `f-string`s and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from index:

```
cats = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

df['Date'] = pd.Categorical(df['Date'], categories=cats, ordered=True)
df1 = df.set_index(['Cust_ID','MCC','Date'])
df1.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df1.columns, 
                                  categories=['TRANS_AMT','Frequency'], 
                                  ordered=True)

df1 = df1.unstack(level=[1,2], fill_value=0).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)

df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}_{c}' for a, b, c in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   Cust_ID  TRANS_AMT_1750_Jan  Frequency_1750_Jan  TRANS_AMT_1799_Jan  \
0        1                6633                   1                5584   
1        2                   0                   0                   0   

   Frequency_1799_Jan  TRANS_AMT_3001_Mar  Frequency_3001_Mar  \
0                   1                   0                   0   
1                   0                 405                   2   

   TRANS_AMT_3174_Oct  Frequency_3174_Oct  
0                   0                   0  
1                1219                   1
```

If not important ordering remove converting to categoricals:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Cust_ID','MCC','Date'])
         .unstack(level=[1,2], fill_value=0)
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}_{c}' for a, b, c in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   Cust_ID  Frequency_1750_Jan  TRANS_AMT_1750_Jan  Frequency_1799_Jan  \
0        1                   1                6633                   1   
1        2                   0                   0                   0   

   TRANS_AMT_1799_Jan  Frequency_3001_Mar  TRANS_AMT_3001_Mar  \
0                5584                   0                   0   
1                   0                   2                 405   

   Frequency_3174_Oct  TRANS_AMT_3174_Oct  
0                   0                   0  
1                   1                1219
```